# Bluetooth in Linux is not working after I dual booted to Garuda Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, bluetooth, garuda-linux

I dual booted My **asus tuf f15** to **Garuda Linux** but the bluetooth doesn't seem to work, i.e, it is totally disabled. I restarted the bluetooth.services and unloaded and loaded the btusb module before doing all of the these.
When I try to connect with `sudo bluetoothctl` it results in the following :

```
sudo bluetoothctl

[sudo] password for rupangkan:
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# scan on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

Here are some details:

```
lsmod | grep btusb

btusb                  69632  0
btrtl                  28672  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                36864  1 btusb
bluetooth             761856  14 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
```

```
journalctl -b | grep Bluetooth

Aug 09 17:40:12 garuda-lappy kernel: Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
Aug 09 17:40:12 garuda-lappy kernel: Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Aug 09 17:40:12 garuda-lappy kernel: Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Aug 09 17:40:12 garuda-lappy kernel: Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Aug 09 17:40:12 garuda-lappy kernel: Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Aug 09 17:40:13 garuda-lappy systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth autoconnect service.
Aug 09 17:40:13 garuda-lappy systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Aug 09 17:40:13 garuda-lappy bluetoothd[491]: Bluetooth daemon 5.60
Aug 09 17:40:13 garuda-lappy systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Aug 09 17:40:13 garuda-lappy systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth Support.
Aug 09 17:40:13 garuda-lappy kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Aug 09 17:40:13 garuda-lappy kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Aug 09 17:40:13 garuda-lappy kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Aug 09 17:40:13 garuda-lappy bluetoothd[491]: Bluetooth management interface 1.20 initialized
Aug 09 17:40:21 garuda-lappy systemd[2530]: Starting Bluetooth OBEX service...
Aug 09 17:40:21 garuda-lappy systemd[2530]: Started Bluetooth OBEX service.
Aug 09 17:40:21 garuda-lappy kded5[2772]: bluedevil: Bluetooth operational changed true
Aug 09 17:40:22 garuda-lappy systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth management mechanism...
Aug 09 17:40:22 garuda-lappy systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth management mechanism.
Aug 09 17:40:33 garuda-lappy systemd[2530]: Started Bluetooth.
```

```
bt-device --list

**
ERROR:lib/bluez/adapter.c:165:adapter_get_dbus_object_path: assertion failed: (ADAPTER_IS(self))
Bail out! ERROR:lib/bluez/adapter.c:165:adapter_get_dbus_object_path: assertion failed: (ADAPTER_IS(self))
fish: Job 1, 'bt-device --list' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

```
lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 322e:202c Sonix Technology Co., Ltd. USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:00a8 Lite-On Technology Corp. Dell Wireless Mouse WM118
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3563 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
lspci -k

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
DeviceName: Onboard - Other
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1e91
Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 05)
DeviceName: Onboard - Video
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 177f
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
DeviceName: Onboard - Other
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1e91
Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
DeviceName: Onboard - Other
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1e91
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
DeviceName: Onboard - Other
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1e91
Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
DeviceName: Onboard - Other
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 201f
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
DeviceName: Onboard - Other
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
DeviceName: Onboard - Other
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1e91
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
DeviceName: Onboard - Other
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1e91
Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 06d3
DeviceName: Onboard - SATA
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1e91
Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b5 (rev f0)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b6 (rev f0)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake LPC Controller
DeviceName: Onboard - Other
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1e91
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1e91
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
DeviceName: Onboard - Other
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1e91
Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
DeviceName: Onboard - Other
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1e91
Kernel driver in use: intel-spi
Kernel modules: intel_spi_pci
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M (rev a1)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 177f
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5404 (rev 03)
Subsystem: Micron Technology Inc Device 1100
Kernel driver in use: nvme
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7961
Subsystem: AzureWave Device 4680
Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
Kernel modules: mt7921e
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 208f
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

```
lsmod | grep mt

mt7921e                90112  0
mt76_connac_lib        45056  1 mt7921e
mt76                   94208  2 mt7921e,mt76_connac_lib
mac80211             1241088  3 mt76,mt7921e,mt76_connac_lib
mtd                    81920  3 spi_nor,intel_spi
cfg80211             1069056  4 mt76,mt7921e,mac80211,mt76_connac_lib
```

`inxi -Fxxxza` gives this about bluetooth :

```
Bluetooth: Device-1: IMC Networks Wireless_Device type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 1-14:3 
chip-ID: 13d3:3563 class-ID: e001 serial: <filter> 
Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: down bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block:
hardware: no software: no address: <filter>
Info: acl-mtu: 0:0 sco-mtu: 0:0 link-mode: slave accept
```

Does anyone have any solution for this I'm pretty new to arch and have been figuring this problem out for over two weeks and am out of ideas.

-

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this helps:

use [rfkill](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/util-linux/rfkill.8.en) to check if your device is disabled and to enable it again

Comment: Bluetooth is not soft or hard blocked so rfkill didn't help at all

Comment: whats "sudo systemctl status bluetooth" reporting?